# Map for one to many relationships

Tags: c++, maps

I need a data structure that can hold one to many relationship.

Some thing like a student can attend many courses. only thing is i might have it in order of thousands. one key to multiple values.

`map<char,int> mymap;` wont allow to insert same key again.

Comment: This is confusing. Do you want multiple equal keys or not?

Comment: Please stop adding additional questions to the original question (clarifications are fine). The original question was answered, there's no incentive for anyone to keep answering a question that keeps changing.

Comment: As long as names of all the students are different std::map is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/) for this.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this:

```
std::map<Student, std::vector<Course>> StudentInfos;
```

You just could use student *id* as key for faster comparison, or you could compare only `id` in `operator<` when comparing two instances of `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::multimap<Key, T>` and `std::multimap<Key, T>::equal_range` if it's okay to duplicate the key a lot. This is probably okay for integers and such.

If you want your key only once, as you will probably want for slightly more complex keys, such as std::string, use `std::map<Key, std::vector<T>>` and its `find` method.

The nested container is more appropriate for your example. The multimap is really only more appropriate if you have different keys that only "seem" identical respective your predicate.